# Query by association in Conceptnet

Tags: conceptnet

I have some code that used to query Conceptnet version 5.4 using the following URL:
http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.4/assoc/c/en/cat?filter=/c/en/dog/.&limit=10

This kind of query used to give you the shared edges between these two concepts. In the latest Conceptnet documentation (https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/API#overview-of-an-api-response) it mentions the API still supports queries by association (it's at the very end of the linked section, this is what the query `assoc` used to do) but in the examples only shows the usage of the `query` kind of query such as http://api.conceptnet.io/query?node=/c/en/dog&other=/c/en/cat

How can I update my URLs to use the new version? Can I use the older API in the new conceptnet.io host?